# Fazer arquivo bat executar powershell como administrador e abrir arquivo ps1

Tags: script, cmd, powershell, prompt

estou enfrentando um problema aqui.

Estou tentando executar um arquivo .ps1 nas maquinas de alguns usuários. O arquivo só pode ser aberto pelo powershell como administrador.

Estamos tentando executar o seguinte comando:

> runas /user:administrator powershell.exe

O comando executa e abre o powershell no modo administrador.

Agora, eu preciso fazer com que o arquivo que está em G:\XXX\arquivo.ps1 seja executado.

Já tentei com:

> runas /user:administrator "powershell.exe G:\XXX\arquivo.ps1"

O comando abre o powershell, mas é encerrado em seguida.

Se vocês souberem uma forma de executar tudo em um único bat, eu agradeceria.

Answer (score 1):

O parâmetro `-command` do Powershell faz o que você está buscando:

```
Executa os comandos especificados (e quaisquer parâmetros) como se fossem
digitados no prompt de comando do Windows PowerShell e depois sai, a menos
que NoExit seja especificado. O valor de Command pode ser "-", uma cadeia 
de caracteres ou um bloco de script.
```

O comando ficaria assim:

```
runas /noprofile /user:administrator "powershell.exe -command G:\xxx\arquivo.ps1"
```

Lembrado que o comportamento continuaria sendo parecido: uma nova janela é aberta, o script `G:\xxx\arquivo.ps1` é executado e em seguida ela é finalizada. Caso queira que a janela continue aberta, use o parâmetro `-noexit`:

```
runas -noprofile /user:administrator "powershell.exe -noexit -command G:\xxx\arquivo.ps1"
```